# Kubernaties unable to mount NFS FS on Google Container Engine

Tags: linux, kubernetes, nfs, google-kubernetes-engine, busybox

I am following the basic nfs server tutorial [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs), however when I am trying to create the test busybox replication controler I get an error indicating that the mount has failed.

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong ?

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume
>   "kubernetes.io/nfs/4e247b33-a82d-11e6-bd41-42010a840113-nfs"
>   (spec.Name: "nfs") pod "4e247b33-a82d-11e6-bd41-42010a840113" (UID:
>   "4e247b33-a82d-11e6-bd41-42010a840113") with: mount failed: exit
>   status 32 Mounting arguments: 10.63.243.192:/exports
>   /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4e247b33-a82d-11e6-bd41-42010a840113/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs
>   nfs [] Output: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   10.63.243.192:/exports, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a
>   /sbin/mount. helper program) In some cases useful info is found
>   in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

I have tried using a ubuntu vm as well just to see if I can manage to mitigate a possible missble `/sbin/mount.nfs` dependency by running `apt-get install nfs-common`, but that too fails with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which container image are you using? On 18th of October Google announce a new container image, which doesn't support NFS, yet. Since Kubernetes 1.4 this image (called `gci`) is the default. See also https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-image-migration#known_limitations

Comment: I am unfortunately using GCI, I wonder if I can create the nfs share in a compute instance and then access it in pods ?

Comment: If I see it correctly, the problem is there because there are missing client libraries/drivers on the Kubernetes instances. So I guess it isn't possible to mount any NFS volumes.